# how use web services in Samsung smart tv app?

Tags: web-services, samsung-smart-tv

I need use web services from a Samsung Smart TV app, but this services need authentication "custom header", there is some way for use https on Samsung smart tv app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arquitecture of aplications on Samsung smart TV allow use JavaScript, and with this JQuery, so we can use AJAX for consume de Web services like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'url/resources/service',
    type: json.type,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data:  {datos},
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings){
        jqXHR.setRequestHeader("head", id);
    },
    success: function(response) {
        alert("Success");
    },
    error: function(response) {    
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

But in the Web Service you need return something in the header :

```
("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
```

**Note:** If you can´t modify the Web service, then this answer won't work for you! But if you can, this solves your problem.

You don´t need implement `https` protocol, because the mapple browser will do it for you, then you connection is secure, y if you Web service it.

Comment: What I've heard is that samsung webkit browser allows cross domain requests by default.